# SQL: How to construct a time series from irregular data and then subsequently calculate a rolling average over it

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate a rolling average of data from incident reports. The exact quantity I'm looking for is the 30-day-mean-time-to-resolution (*mttr*) which means the average of the time it takes to resolve incidents in the last 30 days.

My **incidents** table looks something like this:

```
| incident_id | start_datetime        | end_datetime          |
|-------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| 1           | '2020-02-01T10:13:00' | '2020-02-01T10:59:33' |
| 2           | '2020-02-01T17:55:13' | '2020-02-02T00:35:28' |
| 3           | '2020-02-03T13:33:01' | '2020-02-03T15:54:01' |
```

What I want is something like this (the numbers are made up so don't try to actually calculate-- just note that the datetime intervals are every hour):

```
| datetime              | mttr_last30days_in_hours |
|-----------------------|--------------------------|
| '2020-02-01T10:00:00' | 5.7                      |
| '2020-02-01T11:00:00' | 5.6                      |
| '2020-02-02T12:00:00' | 5.8                      |
```

I can calculate the mttr in the last 30 days really easily if I'm doing it just for one point in time:

```sql
SELECT avg(end_datetime - start_datetime) mttr_last30days_in_hours
FROM incidents
WHERE datetime_diff(current_datetime(), start_datetime, DAY) <= 30
```

The problem is this just gives me ONE number. How do I create a time series spanning the range of say, the first incident's start_datetime (`min(start_datetime)`) to the current time, and then get a rolling 30 day average with evenly spaced, hourly intervals (like the example table above)?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause!

Comment: Actually a group by is not required for the SQL statement I wrote above. Are you referring to the final query that answers my question? If so, it would be helpful to see some code please. Otherwise a group by is not required for just calculating a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unique field in your table, you can try doing that:

```
WITH

t_filter AS(
  SELECT 
     *
  FROM
    incidents 
  WHERE datetime_diff(current_datetime(), start_datetime, DAY) <= 30 
),

t_dates AS (
  SELECT
    unique_key,
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(start_datetime), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS date_array
  FROM
    t_filter
),

t_hour AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
  UNNEST(["00:00:00",
    "01:00:00",
    "02:00:00",
    "03:00:00",
    "04:00:00",
    "05:00:00",
    "06:00:00",
    "07:00:00",
    "08:00:00",
    "09:00:00",
    "10:00:00",
    "11:00:00",
    "12:00:00",
    "13:00:00",
    "14:00:00",
    "15:00:00",
    "16:00:00",
    "17:00:00",
    "18:00:00",
    "19:00:00",
    "20:00:00",
    "21:00:00",
    "22:00:00",
    "23:00:00"]) h 
),

sequence AS(
  SELECT
    unique_key,
    CONCAT(CAST(arr AS string),"T", h) date_hour
  FROM
    t_dates,
    UNNEST(date_array) arr,
    t_hour
)

SELECT
  date_hour,
  AVG(end_datetime - start_datetime)
FROM
  sequence
LEFT JOIN
  t_filter
ON
incidents.unique_key = sequence.unique_key
GROUP BY
  date_hour
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Where does "timestamp" come from? I'm not sure if this solves it

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot changing the field from the query I tested. I just updated the answer now. Can you let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: The thing is, this is fine if we were looking for the dates to be tied to the start_datetime values. However, I want evenly spaced intervals, regardless of the datetimes of the incidents. For example, if the first incident was 1 month ago, I should have every hour between last month and today, regardless of whether or not there was an incident. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah now it makes sense. I updated the answer. It should work fine. If you have some problem or don't understand something, please let me know